# Excel-addin- Office API Javascript - office.js warning and telemetryproxy.html not found

Tags: office-js, office-addins, office-js-helpers

I tried to load my excel-addin on chrome browser.

I have added office.js api and I am getting warning and error in console as
warning: Warning: Office.js is loaded outside of Office client
Error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) telemetryproxy.html

I checked in the network tab and the error: https://telemetryservice.firstpartyapps.oaspapps.com/telemetryservice/telemetryproxy.html  404- file or directory not found.

Can someone help me to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

looks like this URL does no exist. have you ever success? does your add-in ever work in windows?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. You will always get the error "Warning: Office.js is loaded outside of Office client" when you try to open an Office web add-in directly in a browser. Office.js can only initialize in the context of a Office application (Excel, Word, etc.). You have to sideload the add-in to test it. Please see [Sideload an Office add-in for testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/test-debug-office-add-ins#sideload-an-office-add-in-for-testing).

The telemetry service domain is only available to internal Microsoft developers creating add-ins. Since, you are not an internal developer, you get the error; but that error does no harm to the functioning of the add-in.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Here, what data does telemetry service trying to record or transfer?

Comment: For add-ins that Microsoft develops internally and adds as features to the Office products, the telemetry reports usage patterns of the add-in. I don't know the details, but it is not private information.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any possibility to disable/turnoff the telemetry service?